Link equity in a cloned website
If I clone my website to another one, will the cloned website have the backlinks equity?
Like will backlinks split between clones and main website?

This question doesn't make much sense. Why would you ever literally clone a website? If you want to do it for SEO, it's much more damaging than helpful, as duplicate content will be extremely punished if there are lots of duplicate pages.

No, because any external link is pointing to the original site.
The only way to pass the link equity would be to redirect them to your new "cloned" site. However, doing so will remove them from the original site.
